# No puedo remover los elementos de mi lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

En el código que hice creé una ruleta que si el usuario lo quiere puede hacer que la persona no se repita lo cual no me está funcionando y no sé por qué.
Este es el pedazo de código en sí. Si necesitan lo otro me avisan y lo subo

```
i = 1
while True:
   lista_personas = list(range(number_people))
   elegido = choice(lista_personas)
   print("Game", i)
   print("The person who has been selected is: " + str(elegido + 1))
   if repeat == "no" or repeat == "No":
       lista_personas.remove(elegido)
   if veces <= 0:
       break
i += 1
veces -= 1
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Intenta cambiar el `remove` por un `pop`

Comment: No lo puedes hacer porque la lista siempre la creas dentro de cada ciclo while. Saca la lista=lst(rang.... antes del while.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono cuando saque la lista del while